# Javscript create common object from different objects with same attribute and have same key and add amount

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, reduce

> I am trying to get data from JSON :

```
   {
        "data": {
            "Country": [
                {
                    "Area": "Urban",
                    "Date": "2019-10-14T12:14:20.170Z",
                    "income": [
                        {
                            "amount": "33",
                            "currency": "USD"
                        },
                        {
                            "amount": "10",
                            "currency": "INR"
                        }
                    ],
                    "expenditure": [
                        {
                            "amount": "5",
                            "currency": "INR"
                        }
                    ],
                    "tax": [
                        {
                            "amount": "10",
                            "currency": "USD"
                        },
                        {
                            "amount": "10",
                            "currency": "INR"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Area": "Rural",
                    "Date": "2019-10-14T12:14:20.170Z",
                    "income": [
                        {
                            "amount": "2",
                            "currency": "USD"
                        },
                        {
                            "amount": "20",
                            "currency": "INR"
                        }
                    ],
                    "loan": [
                        {
                            "amount": "5",
                            "currency": "INR"
                        }
                    ],
                    "tax": [
                        {
                            "amount": "10",
                            "currency": "USD"
                        },
                        {
                            "amount": "50",
                            "currency": "INR"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

> I want to have a common object which hold data with all unique key such as income,expenditure and then sum the amount which has same currency.

**Need result as below format:**

```
{
"Area": "combined",
"income": [
    {
        "amount": "35",
        "currency": "USD"
    },
    {
        "amount": "30",
        "currency": "INR"
    }
],
"expenditure": [
    {
        "amount": "5",
        "currency": "INR"
    }
],
"loan": [
    {
        "amount": "5",
        "currency": "INR"
    }
],
"tax": [
    {
        "amount": "20",
        "currency": "USD"
    },
    {
        "amount": "60",
        "currency": "INR"
    }
]
}
```

If tried with map and reduce but i can't able to some without using if else statement to check for if value exists inside object is present or not and then do operation.

I tried with below approach:

```
jsonResponse.reduce(
// common_keys passing as hardcoded till loan ,tax etc
(result, { loan,tax}) => {
   forEach(tax, value => {
    const taxObj = find(result.tax, ['currency', value.currency]);
    !taxObj ? result.tax.push(value) : taxObj.amount = Number(taxObj.amount) + Number(value.amount);
  }); 

  forEach(loan, value => {
    const loanObj = find(result.loan, [
      'currencyCode',
      value.currency,
    ]);
    !loanObj ? result.loan.push(value): loanObj.amount = Number(loanObj.amount) + Number(value.amount);
  });
  //repeating for other too

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Any effort so far ? please post the code you have written so far

Comment: that what i come up with so far

Comment: you have one `currency` and more `currencyCode` is it right?

Comment: sorry only currency is there putted wrong json response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With all same `currencyCode`, you could reduce the array and the nested arrays as well.

```js
var data = { data: { Country: [{ Area: "Urban", Date: "2019-10-14T12:14:20.170Z", income: [{ amount: "33", currencyCode: "USD" }, { amount: "10", currencyCode: "INR" }], expenditure: [{ amount: "5", currencyCode: "INR" }], tax: [{ amount: "10", currencyCode: "USD" }, { amount: "10", currencyCode: "INR" }] }, { Area: "Rural", Date: "2019-10-14T12:14:20.170Z", income: [{ amount: "2", currencyCode: "USD" }, { amount: "20", currencyCode: "INR" }], loan: [{ amount: "5", currencyCode: "INR" }], tax: [{ amount: "10", currencyCode: "USD" }, { amount: "50", currencyCode: "INR" }] }] } },
    result = data.data.Country.reduce((r, o) => {
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => {
            if (!Array.isArray(v)) return;
            v.reduce((q, { amount, currencyCode }) => {
                var temp = q.find(t => t.currencyCode === currencyCode);
                if (!temp) q.push(temp = { amount: 0, currencyCode });
                temp.amount = (+temp.amount + +amount).toString();
                return q;
            }, r[k] = r[k] || []);
        });
        return r;
    }, { "Area": "combined" });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```